# jQuery- Dynamically multiply input values of table rows with different id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

**Dynamically adding table rows using below code. User ID is appended for input id.**

```
var selResId = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

    var j=1;
    for (var i=0, il=selResId.length; i < il; i++) {
        var name = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selResId[i], 'USER_NAME');

    $('#addr'+j).html("<td style='text-align:center;'>"+name+"</td><td><input id='hours_"+selResId[i]+"' value='80' type='text' readonly  /></td><td><input id='rate_"+selResId[i]+"' type='text' /></td><td><input name='markup_"+selResId[i]+"' type='text'/></td><td><input name='totalcost_"+selResId[i]+"' type='text' readonly></td>");
    $('#resource_table').append('<tr id="addr'+(j+1)+'"></tr>');
        j++;
        }
    }
```

**HTML Generated**

```
<tr id="addr1">
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly="" value="80" id="hours_10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" id="rate_10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" id="markup_10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly="" value="" id="totalcost_10"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="addr2">
    <td>Foo User</td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly="" value="80" id="hours_11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" id="rate_11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" id="markup_11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" readonly="" value="" id="totalcost_11"></td>
</tr>
```

How do I multiply input values for `hours, rate and markup` and show it under total cost input using below formula. The event could be `keyup`.

```
Initially, totalcost = hours * rate

Case 1: If markup (%) > 0, for eg: 10%, then markup_cost = (hours * rate * markup) / 100
totalcost = (hours * rate) + markup_cost

Case 2: If markup (%) < 0, for eg: -10%, then markup_cost = (hours * rate * markup) / 100
totalcost = (hours * rate) - markup_cost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like,

```
$(function(){
   function setTotalCost(n){
       var h=Number($('#hours_'+n).val()),
           m=Number($('#markup_'+n).val()), // taking 0 if empty
           r=Number($('#rate_'+n).val());
       $('#totalcost_'+n).val(h*m*r);
   }

   $('[id^="rate_"]').on('keyup',function(){
       var n = this.id.replace('rate_','');// get the number
       setTotalCost(n);   
   });
   $('[id^="markup_"]').on('keyup',function(){
       var n = this.id.replace('markup_','');// get the number
       setTotalCost(n);   
   });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
   function setTotalCost(n){
       var h=Number($('#hours_'+n).val()),
           m=Number($('#markup_'+n).val()), // taking 0 if empty
           r=Number($('#rate_'+n).val());
       $('#totalcost_'+n).val(h*m*r);
   }
   
   $('[id^="rate_"]').on('keyup',function(){
       var n = this.id.replace('rate_','');// get the number
       setTotalCost(n);   
   });
   $('[id^="markup_"]').on('keyup',function(){
       var n = this.id.replace('markup_','');// get the number
       setTotalCost(n);   
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="addr1">
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" readonly="" value="80" id="hours_10">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" id="rate_10">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" id="markup_10">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" readonly="" value="" id="totalcost_10">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="addr2">
    <td>Foo User</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" readonly="" value="80" id="hours_11">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" id="rate_11">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" id="markup_11">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" readonly="" value="" id="totalcost_11">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Here, `hours` input will be readonly, so keyup would be called for rate and markup and then `totalcost` will be calculated

Comment: The code seems legit, but does not seem to multiply values based on either rate or markup input resulting in total cost. Also I tried console.log('Test') after keyup function, but it does not seem to be working. Pls check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5nk3g45y/

Comment: Finally I add keyup events for both `rate` and `markup`.

Comment: Actually, the markup could be empty. OI have modified my question for some use cases. `Initially, totalcost = hours * rate

    Case 1: If markup (%) > 0, for eg: 10%, then markup_cost = (hours * rate * markup) / 100
    totalcost = (hours * rate) + markup_cost

    Case 2: If markup (%) < 0, for eg: -10%, then markup_cost = (hours * rate * markup) / 100
    totalcost = (hours * rate) - markup_cost`

Comment: I think the logic is clear to you, and my code is enough for implementing your logic into it. So, try once your logic with my code and if you will have any problems then you can post it here.